# Angular : Scrolling images of carousel next and prev

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap, typescript, carousel

### Changing images with carousel

I am building a web App using **angular** and all is working okay till now, but I am getting a problem while implementing **carousel** in my app, although I have add carousel successfully and its working okay but I am unable to move the carousel items **prev** or **next** by clicking and also they are not moving by their on, I am using **routes** in my app so I have removed the `href` elements from **HTML**.Please help me move the items.

---

**firstpage HTML file:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12">
    <div id="mySlider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" >
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#mySlider" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#mySlider" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#mySlider" data-slide-to="2"></li>
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
          <img src="\assets\images\max.jpg" alt="image 0" style="width:100% ; max-height:400px" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
        <div class="item">
          <img src="\assets\images\MOH.jpg" alt="image 0" style="width:100% ; max-height:400px" class="img-responsive">
        </div>
      </div>

      <a class="left carousel-control"  data-slide="prev" [routerLink]="[index]">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next" [routerLink]="[index]">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Routing.ts:**

```
const gameRoutes: Routes = [
    {path:'', redirectTo: '/main',pathMatch:'full'},
    {path:'main',component:MainPostComponent, children:[
        {path:'',component:StartcomponentComponent},
        {path:':id',component:DetailPostComponent}
    ]},
    {path: 'homepage',component:FirstpageComponent}
]
@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(gameRoutes)],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule{
}
```

Comment: A routed carousel ? Damn, you're not looking for the easy solution there man

Comment: @trichetriche can you venture one please!!